# Ordenar en R en base a un criterio

Tags: r

Me gustaría aprender a ordenar un dataframe (List_Habitat) dependiendo de un criterio propio.

```
 List_habitat:
   Specie          Habitat
   Amaranthus      Crop
   Apiaceae        Edge
   Asteraceae      Quercus
   Malvaceae       Wasteland
```

Quiero ordenar las especies en base a los habitats que el habitat Quercus aparezca antes que el Wasteland, este antes del Edge y por último el hábitat Crop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adrián:

La clave está en convertir la columna «Habitat» en un *factor* ordenado según el criterio que tú prefieras. Sería algo así, siguiendo tu criterio de ordenación:

```
# Dataframe    
List_habitat<-data.frame(Specie=c("Amaranthus", "Apiaceae", "Asteraceae", "Malvaceae"), Habitat=c("Crop", "Edge", "Quercus", "Wasteland"))

# Conversión a factor ordenado según criterio
List_habitat$Habitat<-factor(List_habitat$Habitat, c("Quercus","Wasteland","Edge","Crop"),ordered = TRUE)

# Ordenar dataframe
List_habitat<-List_habitat[order(List_habitat$Habitat),]

List_habitat


Specie   Habitat
3 Asteraceae   Quercus
4  Malvaceae Wasteland
2   Apiaceae      Edge
1 Amaranthus      Crop
```

Saludos